# Invalid android_key parameter

Tags: facebook, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I am creating a Android native application with - HTML5, jQuery Mobile, Phonegap. Here, I have to create login as a facebook. For that I have downloaded phonegap SDK and used in eclipse. I have create AppId in facebook. After that I have generated Key hash. I have entered this has key in the FaceBook. But, I am facing "Invalid android_key parameter" problem. I have gone through all the tutorials and blugs, I have did every things what explained in the tutorials. Help me to come out from this problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing because of you are not using right keystore file, Signed key, and key algorithm. You will need to generate a hash of your Android key(s) and submit those to the Developers page on Facebook.

***If you are generating this hash on Windows (specifically 64 bit versions), please use version 0.9.8e or 0.9.8d of OpenSSL for Windows and not 0.9.8k.***

Once you download openssl, open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as an Administrator, then run the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Please note the `alias_name`, and keep all passwords `andriod`

Now, go to your phonegap account >> edit account >> Click on signing keys tab >> Click 'add a key...' and supply the following info:

```
Title - anything

Alias - alias_name that you have given while generating the keystore file.
```

Then, create a new hash key using the keystore file that you generated and then update that hash key in your facebook app. Use below command to generate hash key.

#### keytool -exportcert -alias [alias_name] -keystore [keystore_filename.keystore] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

That should be it!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.eatapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```